# Trying to get Navbar disappear when page shrinks

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm new to html and css and in my class my teach wants us to make a resume with bootstrap. Obviously the whole point of bootstrap is to be interactive in switching between devices. Im trying to work on aligning stuff and i want my navbar to disappear when I shrink the page. How could I do that?

**HTML**

```
<!-- Bootstrap Import  -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Meta Tags -->
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<!-- Titile and Style  -->
<title>CadenGS's Resume</title>

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Saira+Extra+Condensed:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="script.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
```

```
<!-- Navbar on Side -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg col-lg-2 flex-direction-column justify-content-center">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown"
        aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <!-- Navbar List Items  -->
    <a href="#top"><img id="pfp" src="Images/user_photo.jpg"></a>
    <br>
    <ul class="navbar-nav f-flex flex-column">
        <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#top">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#exp">Experience</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Education</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Skills</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Awards</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Examples</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<section>
    <!-- Used To Scroll To Top of Page for Picture and About on Navbar  -->
    <p id="top">.</p>

    <!-- Content Start  -->
    <div id="main" class="container margin-top-10%">
        <h1 id="primaryName" class="display-2">Caden <span id="secondaryName">Serrato</span></h1>

        <!-- Interactive Contacts -->
        <p class="info" class="display-4"><em>
                <a class="infoLink" onclick="call();">(786) 442-6148</a> · <a class="infoLink"
                    href="emailFiles/email.html" target="_blank">@cserrato21352@columbushs.com</a></em></p>
        <br>
        <p class="info2 display-4"><strong><em>I am a Senior High School Student looking to go into the Field of
                    Engineeing. My
                    goal is to dual major in Mechanical</em></strong></p>
        <p class="info2 display-4" style="text-indent: 80px; margin-top: -10px;"><strong><em>and Engineering, and
                    hopefully one day work at
                    Boston Dynamics.</em></strong></p>

        <!-- Socials  -->
        <div id="socials" class="d-flex flex-direction-row" style="margin-top: 7%;">

            <!-- Github  -->
            <div class="socialHolder">
                <a href="https://github.com/CadenCGS" target="_about">
                    <div class="socialLinks">
                        <img id="gitSocialImg" src="Images/gitSocial.jpg">
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>

            <!-- Instagram  -->
            <div class="socialHolder">
                <a href="https://www.instagram.com/cadenserrato/" target="_about">
                    <div class="socialLinks">
                        <img id="igSocialImg" src="Images/igSocial.png">
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>

            <!-- Facebook  -->
            <div class="socialHolder">
                <a href="https://www.facebook.com/ColumbusHS/" target="_about">
                    <div class="socialLinks">
                        <img id="fbSocialImg" src="Images/fbSocial.png">
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>

            <!-- LinkedIn  -->
            <div class="socialHolder">
                <a href="https://www.linkedin.com" target="_about">
                    <div class="socialLinks">
                        <img id="liSocialImg" src="Images/liSocial.png">
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Used To Scroll To Experience on Navbar  -->
    <p id="exp">.</p>

    <hr class="pageBreak">

    <!-- Experience Section  -->

    <div id="experience" class="container">
        <h1 style="margin-top: 8%; text-indent: 35px; color: rgba(63, 158, 253, .9);"
            class="subSectionName display-3">
            Experience</h1>

        <h1 style="text-indent: 60px; font-size: 3rem; margin-top: 2%;" class="subSectionName display-4">Robotics
        </h1>

        <br>

        <p class="info2 display-4" style="text-indent: 120px;"><strong><em>I started my first year as a simple
                    builder
                    as
                    I
                    learned the basics of Vex. My second year I was a bit more</em></strong></p>
        <p class="info2 display-4" style="text-indent: 60px; margin-top: -10px;"><strong><em> experienced and began
                    to
                    build
                    for advanced and
                    complicated
                    mechanisms. I built all year and ended up finishing </em></strong></p>
        <p class="info2 display-4" style="text-indent: 80px; margin-top: -10px;"><strong><em>in 8th place at the
                    state
                    championship my team qualified for.</em></strong></p>

        <div class="container">
            <hr id="aboveDate">
            <p class="info2 display-4" style="text-indent: 100px; margin-top: 2%;"><strong>Date: <span
                        style="color: rgba(63, 158, 253, 1);">August 2018 -
                        Present</span></strong></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<!-- Bootstrap Scripts  -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
```

**CSS**

````
    height: 4000px;
    background-color: rgb(248, 248, 239);
}

html {
    background-color: rgb(248, 248, 239);
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.navbar {
    background-color: rgba(63, 158, 253, .9);
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    border-right: 9px solid rgb(168, 211, 255);
}

ul {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.nav-link {
    transition: all .25s;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.726);
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.nav-link:hover {
    transition: all .25s;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: darkslategrey;
    font-size: 1.7rem;
}

#pfp {
    border: 9px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .4);
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 160px;
    width: 160px;
    position: static;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#primaryName {
    font-family: 'Saira Extra Condensed';
    color: rgb(146, 146, 146);
    font-size: 6rem;
}

#secondaryName {
    font-family: 'Saira Extra Condensed';
    color: rgba(63, 158, 253, .9);
    font-size: 6rem;
}

#main {
    padding-top: 10%;
    margin-left: 7%;
}

.info {
    font-size: 1.7rem;
}

.info2 {
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    text-indent: 30px;
}

#top,
#exp {
    color: rgba(63, 158, 253, 0);
}

.infoLink {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Saira Extra Condensed';
    color: rgb(110, 110, 110);
}

.infoLink:hover {
    color: black;
}

#emailLink {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}

.socialHolder {
    margin-left: 3%;
}

.socialLinks {
    height: 65px;
    width: 65px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: rgb(146, 146, 146);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    transition: all .25s;
}

.socialLinks:hover {
    transition: all .25s;
    background-color: rgb(75, 75, 75);
}

#gitSocialImg {
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 55%;
    width: 55%;
    margin-top: 25%;
}

#igSocialImg {
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 80%;
    width: 80%;
    margin-top: 11%;
}

#fbSocialImg {
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 55%;
    width: 55%;
    margin-top: 22%;
}

#liSocialImg {
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 55%;
    width: 55%;
    margin-top: 22%;
}

.pageBreak {
    border: 2px solid rgba(63, 158, 253, .9);
    width: 85%;
    margin-top: 4%;
    margin-right: 13%;
}

.subSectionName {
    font-family: 'Saira Extra Condensed';
    color: rgb(146, 146, 146);
}

.subSectionInfo {
    font-family: 'Saira Extra Condensed';
    color: rgb(110, 110, 110);
    font-size: 1.7rem;
    margin-left: 60px;
}

#experience {
    margin-left: 4.6%;
}

#aboveDate {
    border: 2px solid rgba(63, 158, 253, .9);
    width: 27.5%;
    margin-left: 6%;
    margin-bottom: -1%;
}```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a [media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) and than do [display: none;](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) on the element you want to disappear.

Example:

```
@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .navbar {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: for those checking this in JSFiddle this solution doesn't seem to work: but changing `display: none;` into `display: none !important;` will fix the issue

Comment: That's interesting that it doesn't work in JSFiddle. In general it's not best practice to use !important https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/